# Reg ex to validate column names with alias

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written Reg ex to validate my input string which is contains column names with aliases as comma separated. but when i try to run with long string i am getting below error in regex101.com
Catastrophic backtracking has been detected and the execution of your expression has been halted.

and when i try in node app, getting 504 timeout exception.

Reg ex is:

^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+( (as){1}[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)?,?)+$

```
try{

  const paragraph = `column1 as column Id,column2 as column3,column3 as column3 Name(),xxx as xxx xxx xxx Date(u)`;
  const found = paragraph.match(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+( (as){1}[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)?,?)+$/);
  console.log(found);
  } 
   catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
```

Comment: Google "catastrophic backtracking"

Comment: FYI `{1}` is redundant. A pattern always matches exactly 1 time unless you quantify it.

Comment: Why don't you use `paragraph.split(',')` to deal with the commas, then match each of those strings with a regexp?

Comment: You might use a pattern like `^\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+(?:,\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/fqPC2H/1 adding the characters that are present in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to repeat the whole pattern with the nested quantifiers.

The issue of [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) occurs when the pattern can not match a parenthesis, and will still try all the possible options allowed by the quantifiers.

You could use an unrolled version instead, and note that this does not validate the syntax of the language used, only the possible format of the string.

```
^\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+(?:,\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+)*$
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `\w+ as` Match 1+ word chars, space and  `as`
- `(?: [\w()]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching a space and one if the listed in the character class
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\w+ as` Match a `,` 1+ word chars and  `as`
  - `(?: [\w()]+)+`  Match  1 or more repetitions of a space and any of the listed chars as there can be more than 1 "words" after  `as`
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fqPC2H/1)

```js
const paragraph = `column1 as column Id,column2 as column3,column3 as column3 Name(),xxx as xxx xxx xxx Date(u)`;
const found = paragraph.match(/^\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+(?:,\w+ as(?: [\w()]+)+)*$/);
console.log(found);
```

Comment: @user2818541 you could shorten it to https://regex101.com/r/M5LNrJ/1

Comment: @user2818541 Like this? https://regex101.com/r/Elt1j3/1

Comment: @user2818541 You can match the comma separated values without a space, and then match a space followed by https://regex101.com/r/muSGVI/1

Comment: @user2818541 Can you share a regex101 link with that longer text?

Comment: please follow this link https://regex101.com/r/I75F85/1

Comment: @user2818541 Ah, I see. Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/NMgFwi/1

Comment: In this link, i wanted to fail first string and pass second string .
In the string i want to allow only characters, numbers and _

https://regex101.com/r/aSS7We/1

Please suggest

Comment: @user2818541 That really depends on what you would allow to match. This will match only word characters separated by a space. https://regex101.com/r/ZN44Lb/1 Shall we clean up some of our comments?